# How can I set TIMESTAMP's default to future date?

Tags: mysql, timestamp, default-value

I know I can set default value with current timestamp like this

```
... DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Is there any way to set the column with fixed amount of units based on current timestamp?

```
... DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + 10 days?
```

Comment: You'll have to use a trigger, as you can't use functions for MySQL defaults

Comment: Yeah, I tried. Even `TRIGGER`s appear to be a bitch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a trigger:

```
mysql> CREATE TRIGGER dateinsert BEFORE INSERT ON testtable
    -> FOR EACH ROW
    -> SET NEW.yourdate =  DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),INTERVAL 10 DAY);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into testtable (blah) values (1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from testtable;
+------+------------+
| blah | yourdate   |
+------+------------+
|    1 | 2016-07-25 |
+------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```